# Getting nth node from a linked list

Tags: java

I have these code:
Class File:

```
public class LinkedListCustom<T> implements AbstractList<E>
{
    private int numElements; private Node head, tail;
    ...
    ...

    public Node(T element)
    {
         T data; 
         Node next, prev;
    }
    ...
    ...
    private Node getNthElem(int index)
    {
        Node temp = head;
        for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
        {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public T getNthVal(int index)
    {
       Node n = getNthElem(index);
       return n.data;
    }

}
```

Test file:

```
public class Tester extends TestCase
{
    public void testGetN()
    {
        MyCustomLinkedList<Integer> myList = new MyCustomLinkedList<Integer>();
        myList.add(1);
        myList.add(2);
        assertEquals("index 0 is 1", new Integer(2), myList.getNthValue(1);
    }
}
```

However, this does not run properly. May I know what I could have done wrongly? If there is anything unclear I'll clarify it immediately.

**EDIT: It compiles but there is a NullPointerException.**

**EDIT 2: *SOLVED* Sorry about the vague question and unclear code, but I just wanted to find out what I might not have implemented, and it turns out that @JaviFernandez was correct by asking whether I have implemented the add() method, which I didn't. I was just looking for an answer like that... Sorry if I have troubled anyone...**

Comment: Can you include the `add` method code?

Comment: It won't even *compile*, much less run.

Comment: Can you show the `assertEquals` code?

Comment: You should have posted the stack trace in your question, but if you have a linked list you shouldn't be performing direct access on it at all, only sequential access.

Comment: I think I've found out the answer, I haven't properly implemented the add() method. Thank you @JaviFernández! (I'm creating my custom linked list, so I didn't really want to copy the whole code to save time, which is a bad thing, so I apologize.)

Comment: @ThatWeirdo This is standard JUnit: http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/Assert.html#assertEquals(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)

Comment: @B.A. glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

When you say `getNthValue(1)`, this returns you the value at index 1, which is the second element since indices are 0-based. So in your linked list, you have the value `1` at index 0, and the value `2` and index 1.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is really useful to describe how it didn't work. Was there a message? What happened versus what you were expecting to happen?

Comment: NullPointerException. So I guess it kind of worked but I had an error somewhere. Will update the question to reflect this. Sorry about the lack of clarity, that's why I added that comment below the test code.

Comment: If you're getting a null pointer exception the problem should be in the constructor or the `add` method. Can you include their code?

Answer (score 0):

> private Node getNth(int index)

is missing a `return`:

> return temp;

Comment: It was a bug and I've fixed it but the code still didn't work. So it's a bigger problem or something.

Comment: @B.A. is the problem that it does not compile?

Comment: @B.A. If you please, include the whole code without any gaps marked by `...` in your answer. Then we could maybe help

Comment: @JaviFernández It compiles but the test fails.